# Error on mysql insets: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, node.js

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I have 2 mysql insert functions in my code. When my second insert function has nothing to insert, and is not called to run, I get this error message. If both insert functions have data to insert, the program works ok and no error messages.

I tried to modify my config file containing the connection details setting to mysql and set multipleStatements: true, but this did not help. Both insert statements work when I run them in mysql.

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO stock_feed_periodic (symbol,price,ts) VALUES ?`;
insertValuesToDB(sql, values);

let sql2 = `INSERT INTO stock_feed_unusuals (symbol,price,ts) VALUES ?`;
if (unusuals) insertValuesToDB(sql2, unusuals);

function insertValuesToDB(sql, values) {
    conn.query(sql, [values], function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return;
    });
}
```

config.js file:
    const mysql = require("mysql");

```
// create a connection variable with the required details
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost", // ip address of server running mysql
    user: "****",
    password: "*****",
    database: "stocks"
});

module.exports = conn;
```

I only get the message when the object unusuals is undefined and then the second function should not run. 
If its defined, both insets run ok. Very strange. Is it something to do with mysql configuration options?

Comment: I do not think it is related to mysql. It is just that condition checks for existence of unusuals , if it not there , it complains

Comment: The correct syntax is `INSERT INTO stock_feed_unusuals (symbol, price, ts) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Is it one question mark per field?
Adding more question marks doesn't seem to make a difference. Still getting the error.

Comment: In general, it's one value per column (and everything inside brackets). Otherwise, how's MySQL going to know which value goes where?